# @font-face not rendering on first page visit

Tags: html, css, fonts, rendering, font-face

I've added three fonts to my page with the @font-face css operative. Surfing to the page http://www.oefentherapie-fysiotherapie.nl/index.html shows the page, but does not load the fonts. Refreshing the page does not help. Browsing to another page does render the fonts, and returning to the original page with the back button makes the page render the font correctly.

The css for the page is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller Regular';
    src: url('Aller_Rg.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('Aller_Rg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('Aller_Rg.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('Aller_Rg.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('Aller_Rg.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    src: url('Aller_Bd.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('Aller_Bd.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('Aller_Bd.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('Aller_Bd.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('Aller_Bd.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Turnpike';
    src: url('/css/Turnpike.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/css/Turnpike.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/css/Turnpike.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('/css/Turnpike.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('/css/Turnpike.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Are the fonts not rendering because the file is too large, so it is not completely read before the page is displayed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser? All of them?

Comment: Yup. Tested it on android, iOS, chome and Firefox. IE is untested.

Comment: Hmm...s'working for me in Chrome 41.0.2272.17 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: How big are your files. Have you cleared your browser cache? I tested it and it loaded on the first try. Seems like a caching issue. `ctrl+F5` does a hard refresh of the page.

Comment: the woff files are around 44k-48k, the ttf files are 131k, 128k, and 48k respectively. I've also repeatedly used [ctrl] + [f5]

Comment: I've been debugging it with the developer console open. The fonts all return "206 partial content". I found out that if I leave out the [www.], the fonts don't get downloaded correctly. If I add it, they are downloaded with 200 ok, and are rendered correctly.